# Using the same event code in several controls in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

i want to use the same code which is :-

```
Private Sub Text_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode >= 48 And KeyCode <= 57 Then
     'allow
Else
      If KeyCode >= 96 And KeyCode <= 105 Then
          'allow
      Else
           If KeyCode = 8 Or KeyCode = 9 Or KeyCode = 13 Or KeyCode = 27 Or KeyCode = 46 Then
               'allow
           Else: KeyCode = 0
           End If
      End If
End If
End Sub
```

in multiple textboxes which are located in several forms,and i don't want to repeat the same code over an over,how can i achieve that?
thank you in advance

Comment: Hi there. Why not make a function?

Comment: Put the function into a module, and make it a `Public Sub` and you can call it from anywhere in the forms easily enough.

Comment: tried that ,didn't work ,i added a function at the end of the form and called it onlyNum and paste the code inside of it,and in the event i typed the function name,did i do somthing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ryan suggested - use a function.

Add this function to a normal module:

```
Public Function AllowKeyCode(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer) As Integer
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 48 To 57, 96 To 105, 8, 9, 13, 27, 46
            AllowKeyCode = KeyCode
        Case Else
            AllowKeyCode = 0
    End Select
End Function
```

Use this code for your keydown event:

```
Private Sub Text0_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    KeyCode = AllowKeyCode(KeyCode, Shift)
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
You may want to change the function to take into account the shift button (to stop !,",£, etc.):

```
Public Function AllowKeyCode(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer) As Long

    If Shift = 0 Then
        Select Case KeyCode
            Case 48 To 57, 96 To 105, 8, 9, 13, 27, 46
                AllowKeyCode = KeyCode
            Case Else
                AllowKeyCode = 0
        End Select
    Else
        AllowKeyCode = 0
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Note, putting the function in a standard module makes the function more visible than it needs to be. Encapsulating it as a member of a **class module** makes it visible only to code that explicitly creates an instance of that class, so you could have a `Private validator As New KeyCodeValidator` private field in all forms that need it, and then do `KeyCode = validator.AllowKeyCode(KeyCode, Shift)` instead of calling a globally-scoped function.

Comment: I would also make the function pass the parameters by value (`ByVal`), to better communicate the intent.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook ,thanks, i forgot all about the shift key ,thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Darren's answer, you could even do a *subfunction* saving you further typing:

```
Public Sub AllowKeyCode(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 48 To 57, 96 To 105, 8, 9, 13, 27, 46
            ' Allow KeyCode.
        Case Else
            KeyCode = 0
    End Select

End Sub
```

and then it can't be simpler:

```
Private Sub Text0_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    AllowKeyCode KeyCode, Shift

End Sub
```

Comment: Except it's much clearer that a `Function` **returns** a value, as opposed to a `Sub` that assigns a `ByRef` parameter. Reading `KeyCode = AllowKeyCode(KeyCode, Shift)` makes it much clearer what's going on *without having to read through the actual implementation to see which ByRef parameter is being mutated*.

Comment: You might have also to touch parameter _Shift_ which would easily be accomplished with the sub.